# I have passed array of object to <li> "value" attribute and then attached that array to state but its not rendering into html

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, react-hooks

This is the data which i want to render the correspondant data assigne to value attribute in li tag is assigned here in a state i.e, otherState in my case

```
const [otherDetails, setOtherDetails] = React.useState([]);

const state = {
  listitems: [
    {
      id: 1,
      vendorContact: "User 1",
      otherDetails: [
        {
          firstName: 'U',
          lastName: 'I',
          city: 'O',
          zip: '560084'
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      vendorContact: "User 2",
      otherDetails: [
        {
          firstName: 'D',
          lastName: 'N',
          city: 'W',
          zip: '560084'
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      vendorContact: "User 3",
      otherDetails: [
        {
          firstName: 'A',
          lastName: 'B',
          city: 'V',
          zip: '560084'
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
};
```

And Here i have to render the data under

NOTE: I am passing array of object to the value attribute of li

```
<ul className="sidenavList">
  {state.listitems.map(listitem => (
    <li key={listitem.id} className="row" value={listitem.otherDetails} onClick={handleSelection}>
      {listitem.vendorContact}
    </li>
  ))}
</ul>
```

Finally this is place where i am trying to display the data using react

```
<div className="right"> {
  <span>{otherDetails}</span>
  }
</div>
```

> Updating the state on even

```
 const handleSelection = (e) => {
e.preventDefault();
setOtherDetails(e.target.getAttribute('value'))
```

}

Comment: You have to mention what is not working and what is your question.

Comment: @TusharShahi either the state is not getting updated or the array of object is not getting assigned to <li> value attribute

Comment: Your list is stored in a variable named `state` but is not part of state in the eyes of react. Also you are assigning and array of objects to the `value` attribute of your `li` which will be coerced to a string, how will you utilize this later?

Comment: @pilchard so what is the best way i can take to render child array into a li

Comment: As per the requirement i have to show a navbar inside a popup and based on the item select on navbar i have to render the correspondent child value to the next div element. that is if on navbar user click  vendorContact: "User 2", then its corresponding array of object   otherDetails: [
        {
          firstName: 'U',
          lastName: 'I',
          city: 'O',
          zip: '560084'
        }
      ] has to be populated on the next div

Comment: @pilchard i want to add a check box before vendor name and once user slect vendor name checkbox i want that vendorId to be updated in an array and delete it when user uncheck

Comment: You'll need to ask another question with the relevant code for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't answer all of your specific needs as per your comment, but here is a basic implementation that assigns a unique `id` to each element which can then be used in the click handler to retrieve the appropriate item and update the state with it. I'm not sure what your needs for the `state` variable are, whether they're coming as a prop or should be managed as their own `useState` element.

```js
const App = () => {
  const [otherDetails, setOtherDetails] = React.useState([]);

  const state = { listitems: [{ id: 1, vendorContact: "User 1", otherDetails: [{ firstName: 'U', lastName: 'I', city: 'O', zip: '560084' }] }, { id: 2, vendorContact: "User 2", otherDetails: [{ firstName: 'D', lastName: 'N', city: 'W', zip: '560084' }] }, { id: 3, vendorContact: "User 3", otherDetails: [{ firstName: 'A', lastName: 'B', city: 'V', zip: '560084' }] }] };

  const handleSelection = (e) => {
    const targetItem = state.listitems.find(({ id }) => id == e.target.id)
    setOtherDetails(targetItem.otherDetails)
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <ul className="sidenavList">
        {state.listitems.map(listitem => (
          <li key={listitem.id} id={listitem.id} className="row" onClick={handleSelection}>
            {listitem.vendorContact}
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
      {otherDetails.length ?
        <div className="right">
          {otherDetails.map(detail => (
            Object.entries(detail).map(([key, val]) => (
              <p>{key}<span> {val}</span></p>
            ))
          ))}
        </div>
        : null}
    </div>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```